# Can I delete the xib file completely?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been converting a simple program that uses a xib file to be done programatically. I've removed the elements one by one and put them back in in the code.

Can I eventually delete the entire file? or is it used for something vital?

There seem to be three.

PhoneContent.xib
MyView.xib
MainWindow.xib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the MyView.xib or PhoneContent.xib so you can just delete them if you've recreated the layouts in code.

To remove MainWindow.xib, you will need to update the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method to set up the window and main view controller programmatically, but more subtly than that you'll need to modify the main function in main.m

Instead of looking like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

You'll need it to look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([YourAppDelegate class]));
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

You'll also have to delete the reference to MainWindow (Main nib file base name) from your info.plist file.

Okay. So now I've told you how to delete your nib files, do you mind if I ask *why* you are doing it? Generating layouts in code is madness! It's like trying to generate HTML in JavaScript, or generate a picture by specifying the colors as hexadecimal numbers ina  text file.

You're taking an interface which is easy to tweak visually without needing to compile and run each time you move something a few pixels, and making it much harder to maintain.

You're taking layout code that is guaranteed to be bug free because it is generated automatically, and replacing it with loads of hand-written code that could be full of memory leaks or conceptual errors.

What have you got against nib files?

Comment: I've been removing XIBs from some of my projects recently because if I want to use it in a library project it's a lot easier to have everything done in code. That's one reason. But I agree it can be a right pain to do some UIs programatically.

Comment: basically I'm working for a little start-up and they've asked me to create a news feed type thing entirely in code. I suppose if it's completely code it can just be added to various other projects, but I think they mainly asked me to do it like that to learn how everything fits together.

Comment: FYI, you can include xib files in a bundle and distribute that along with your static library. You'd use that approach for images and other assets anyway, so it's not really a burden. You can use the bundle argument of initWithNibName:bundle: to specify that the nib for a viewcontroller should be loaded from your library bundle instead of the application main bundle.

Comment: I get a SIGABRT from this code on the line with the nameOfAppDelegateClass bit (and I have changed it to my actual delegate class)

Comment: You may also need to remove the "Main nib file base name" value from your info.plist as Ali3n suggests.

Comment: I've done that, still getting the error. also I'm coming from using visual studio and am finding it incredibly frustrating that I get no other error info other than SIGABRT. how do I get into that error?

Comment: It's also better practice to use NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]) as Michał Zygar suggested instead of a hard-code string, because that way if you rename your app delegate it will be updated in the main function, or throw a compile time error instead of crashing at runtime (that won't be the reason why it's crashing for you now though - that will be due to the MainWindow in the info.plist)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can delete all .xib files. If you delete MainWindow.xib remember to init your window in your `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and then set the root view controller

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

also -as Nick Lockwood mentioned- check main.m to see if the `UIApplicationDelegate` class is set (done by default by Xcode4.2 and above)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Finally, remove `Main nib file base name` property from `<App>-Info.plist` file.

Comment: this line is already in the appDelegate: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` should I replace it still?

Comment: Nope, if you have it, there is nothing more to do.

Comment: it is slightly different though. similarly I also have these lines: `[self.window addSubview:contentController.view];/
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Comment: crap, I was wrong, you SHOULD add the autorelease method to `UIWindow alloc]...` prevent leaking. If you have the other lines and changed -Info.plist, you are all set

Comment: I get a SIGABRT on the UIApplicationMain line. Do I have to include the AppDelegate as a header or something?

Comment: `AppDelegate` should be your `UIApplicationDelegate` class, i.e. `PhotoblogAppDelegate`, `SMAppDelegate` and you should import header as well

Comment: I still get a SIGABRT. I'm actually using your exact line of code because my AppDelegate is called exactly that. Or do I need to access the appDelegate already in there or something? sorry, I'm just totally new to all this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6824/discussion-between-michal-zygar-and-siryakalot)

Answer (score 3):

you also need to delete the main XIb value from the App_info.plist